# How can I prevent Windows responding to a mouse media button?

Tags: windows-8, mouse

**Background**: I broke two fingers on my right hand recently, and have mallet splints on them.

My mouse has a couple of media buttons on them for email and internet:

[image: mouse 1]

Right beside my temporarily-enlarged index finger position:

[image: mouse 2]

Which is quite inconvenient if I'm (say) playing MGSV:TPP about to be discovered after a long mission and when I click, instead of tranq'ing the guard in the head instead I see this pop up:

[image: fudging email]

And hear the alert sound and the mission failure go on in the background. As a *purely hypothetical* example, I imagine that would be quite frustrating.

Having Windows respond to the mouse media button is quite inconvenient.

I have searched for how to disable this, but other solutions seem to cover:

- disabling media keys altogether via Accessibility Tools
- remapping/disabling keyboard-specific media keys<sup>1</sup>
- are Windows 10-specific (eg a reference to `Mouse and Keyboard` options, which I don't have)

None of these quite solves the problem.

**How can I disable the media keys on the mouse in Windows 8?**

<sup><sup>1</sup>: It's possible that the mouse is sending the same event as the keyboard. Can I check this? I would be happy to disable the email media button event from both the mouse and keyboard, but not all media keys.</sup>

Comment: It might be obvious, but have you thought about swapping your mouse for a 3-button model until the splints are removed? This will be a cheap solution, unless you particularly need a high-precision gaming mouse. Also, one of my erstwhile colleagues, though right-handed, trained himself to use a mouse left-handed, as it helped him to organise his desk better: he soon gained the same facility as right-handed use.

Comment: @AFH That's a reasonable suggestion for a workaround to be fair, but for a few reasons I'd prefer not to buy a mouse for the sake of a few weeks :) I could indeed swap hands, but that would leave me unable to use a hand to `wasd` (etc), as in the maybe-not-entirely-hypothetical example of MGSV:TPP!

Comment: Thank you for not posting the gory x-rays! ;)